# Ebean creates objects on start?

Tags: java, database, playframework, ebean

I have created example application that uses Ebeans:

Model:

```
@Entity
public class Numm extends Model {

    @Id
    private long id;

    public long number;

    @Transient
    static long counter = 0;

    public Numm() {
        number = counter++;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public static Result index() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Numm numm = new Numm();
        numm.save();
    }
}
```

...and Numm objects in DB are:

```
id, number
1, 4
2, 5
3, 6 
4, 7
5, 8
6, 9
7, 10
8, 11
9, 12
10, 13
```

Why first row is not

```
1, 0
```

is it a bug? My assumption is that Ebeans created some objects on start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ebean creates some objects on start to make some checking if model is correct. As example you can see `setBeanReflect` method from [BeanDescriptorManager](https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/avaje/ebeaninternal/server/deploy/BeanDescriptorManager.java) class.

Ebean creates 4 objects for each model class and some time later creates another 4 objects. So you cannot rely on counter increased in default constructor.

But there is one workaround. You can add parameter to your constructor. For example:

```
public Numm(int a) {
    number = counter++;
}
```

and then in your controller:

```
public static Result index() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Numm numm = new Numm(0);
        numm.save();
    }
}
```

Then instances created in above loop will have numbers starting from 0.

Comment: Ok - so it will be ok if I will use counter in non-default constructors